# Solr DataImportHandler logs into SQL but never fetches any data

Tags: sql-server-2008, configuration, jdbc, solr

Hi I have copied my Solr config from a working windows server to a new one, and it can't seem to run an import.

They're both using win server 2008 and SQL 2008R2. This is the data import config:

```
<dataConfig>  
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"  name="ds1"
        driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"  
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=DB"   
        user="Solr"  
        password="pwd"/>  
  <document name="datas">  
    <entity name="data" dataSource="ds1" pk="key"
    query="EXEC SOLR_COMPANY_SEARCH_DATA"
    deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM Company_Search_Data WHERE [key]='${dataimporter.delta.key}'"
    deltaQuery="SELECT [key] FROM Company_Search_Data WHERE modify_dt > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">  
          <field column="WorkDesc_Comments" name="WorkDesc_Comments_Split" />
          <field column="WorkDesc_Comments" name="WorkDesc_Comments_Edge" />
    </entity>  
  </document>  
</dataConfig>
```

I can use MS SQL Profiler to watch the Solr user log in successfully, but then nothing. It doesn't seem to even try and execute the stored procedure. Any ideas why this would be working one server and not on another?

FTR the only thing in the tomcat catalina log is:

```
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1 call
INFO: Creating a connection for entity data with URL: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=CATLive
```

**UPDATE:**
Me and Yavar Husain from the Solr Mailing list both came up with the solution of replacing the MS JDBC Driver with an open source one - this seems to work, and means this must be a compatibility problem between the latest versions of Java, the DIH and the MS JDBC driver.

**UPDATE 2:**
Issues have been reported with Java 1.6.0_29 - *which I am running!*
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2011/11/07/supported-java-versions-november-2011.aspx

Comment: So I've established there's no problem in the DB - I can import from this DB to my old Solr server. I'm using Jetty instead of Tomcat and I have also simplified the data import config/solr schema as far as possible (importing 4 rows of strings from one table into one field). But still nothing - the importhandler just doesn't do anything.

Comment: This is crazy. I've created a new Solr install on a new machine, and again, it doesn't work. Once I got through the config problems, it just does nothing again.

Comment: I've opened an issue on Solr's bug tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2980

Comment: STW: I'm pretty sure it's the issue with Java 1.6.0_29 - because that was the difference between the machine that worked and the one that didn't (the one that didn't work HAD that version, for clarity!)

Comment: I think you're mostly correct; in my case both the working and non-working machines were on the same release of the JRE; however they were using slightly different builds of that release.  See my updated answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks to have been caused by a release of Java 1.6.0_29 - which I was running:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2011/11/07/supported-java-versions-november-2011.aspx

Comment: Sorry - why downvote? This *was* the answer for me. I can't see how that would ever need downvoting?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, but I just upvoted.  Confirmed _30 worked for me.  Can be picked up for the mac at http://connect.apple.com and it's the release from December 22, 2011.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as the problem could only be with the JDBC drivers or their config, I have worked around this issue by replacing them with the [jTDS Open Source JDBC driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/). My config ended up like this when I got it working with that:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=DBName" 
              user="Solr" 
              password="password" name="ds1"/>
  <document>
    <entity dataSource="ds1" name="sometext" 
            query="SELECT * FROM mytable">
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

HTH someone - but I'm not marking this as the answer because I can't see why I can't use the MS drivers...

Comment: Now I have the problem that running a delta update updates the
'dataimport.properties' file - but then just re-fetches all the data
regardless! Weird!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing this

**url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname"**

dbname -> \SQL2008

Comment: No? That string works on the other server - it's MSSQL, not mysql - hence jdbc:sqlserver. Do you mean instance name? I believe it's the default instance, so I shouldn't need to supply the name (and don't on the other server).

Comment: Tried some combinations here - most notably: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/MSSQLSERVER (MSSQLSERVER is the name listed in Services.msc) as well as the name of the server instead of localhost and instead of MSSQLSERVER - but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I presume when you copied your Solr config to the new server you've taken the index file too. I suspect the problem is due to the fact that Solr has already indexed this data. Your query states that you only want to index files that have changes since the last index.

Does this make sense?

Comment: I've tried starting again from scratch using the example, twice on two different servers. Also when you start a 'full-import' it clears the data to start with by default (which I can see working fine).

Comment: Are there any clues in the Jetty output window?

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to occur only on very specific releases of the java runtime, and affects applications beyond just solr.  This leads me to believe that the root cause is an incompatibility or bug between the Java runtime and Microsoft SQL Server JDBC drivers rather than being a Solr issue.

In my particular case we had two groups consisting of 3 servers each.  One group showed no symptoms of this problem, and the other group all exhibited issues.  All servers were running Solr 3.4.0, and the same release of SQL Server JDBC drivers 3.0.  All servers were also running JRE 1.6.0_20, *but* upon closer inspection it was identified that the problem servers were using a slightly newer package for 1.6.0_20 (a different RPM distributed via `yum` for CentOS).

By downgrading the problem servers to the exact version of java on the known-good servers the problem immediately went away.

Specifically,

working:
http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/centos-rhel-x86_64/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-1.22.1.9.8.el5_6.x86_64.rpm.html

non-working:
http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/centos-rhel-updates-x86_64/java-1.6.0-openjdk-src-1.6.0.0-1.23.1.9.10.el5_7.x86_64.rpm.html